# click to toggle for better performances approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('.head').click(function(){
    $(".content").toggle();

    if($('.content').is(':visible')) {
        $('.head> img').attr('src', downIcon);
    }
    else {
        $('.head> img').attr('src', rightIcon);
    }
});
```

I think this is not the best way to switch the accordion icon, because there is a slightly delay.

Any thoughts on improving this to a better performances approach?

Comment: Could you provide the relevant HTML? Also, a jsfiddle would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `div` element with `background-image` set to the icon you want to use instead of the `img` element. Then just toggle an extra class which describes the current icon state.

**HTML**

```
<div class="head"><div class="icon"></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.head > .icon {
    background-image: url('up-image.png');
}
.head > .icon.visible {
    background-image: url('down-image.png');
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.head').click(function(){
    $(".content").toggle();
    if ($('.content').is(':visible')) {
        $('.head > .icon').addClass('visible');
    } else {
        $('.head > .icon').removeClass('visible');
    }
});
```